# Toldos Noach vs Toldos Yitzchok

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are parshat Noach and parshat Toldot named that way?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10936/why-are-parshat-noach-and-parshat-toldot-named-that-way)

Was wondering. Why is Parshas Toldos not called Parshas Yitzchok just like Parshas Noach. In addition why is Parshas Noach not called Parshas Toldos?